# Does the question belong in Electrical Engineering?

Tags: discussion

I wrote a program that computes the fast **insert_name_here** transform of a matrix. I am at a loss of what its application is, what its proper name should be, and find an existing algorithm for it. I posted this question in Computer Science, and one of their members suggested it might be better served here. Does this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51446/what-can-i-do-with-this-algorithm) belong in Electrical Engineering? Thanks.

Comment: A solution in search of a problem ... ? I agree with Dave's answer.

Comment: Why did you write the code in the first place if you don't know of any use for it?

Answer (score 6):

To be honest, it sounds more like a [pure math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) problem to me.

Comment: Agree, and almost posted the same answer.  The thing that stopped me is the part that says "what its application is".

Comment: @ScottSeidman: The problem is that the OP can't identify an application for the algorithm, in EE or any other field. I think that only a mathematician would be familiar with the terminology used in the question and be able to identify a field in which he's seen it before.